# Php Login Script - Security Review and Suggestions

Tags: php, security, authentication

I write a simple php login class that only operate on php sessions to login user in the system.

My Question is that this class is secure enough to be used on **production environment** ?
**class.login.inc.php**

```
class Login
{

//setSessionFunction sets a login session with user id and all user details array

private function setSession($user_id,$user_details)
{
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  $_SESSION['user_details'] = $user_details;
  $_SESSION['key'] = $this->hashSession();
}

//GetIp function is used to get ip address of client
private function hashSession()
{
return sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . getIP());
}


//get sessions and verify them
public function getSession(){

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && ($_SESSION['user_id']!== '') )
 if($this->verifySessionUser($_SESSION['user_id']) === true )
  if($this->hashSession() == $_SESSION['key'])
return true;
else
 return false;


}


//Logout Function 
public function logout(){
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = null;
   $_SESSION['key'] = null;
   $_SESSION = array();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
}
public function verifyUser($username,$password){
  $password = sha1($password);
  $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$conn) die("Connection Error To DATABASE" . mysqli_connect_errno());
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
  $mysqli = $conn->prepare($sql);
  if(!$conn) die("Query Error To DATABASE In Class Session" . mysqli_errno($conn));
  $mysqli->bind_param("s",$username);
  $mysqli->execute();
  $result = $mysqli->get_result();
  $mysqli->close();
  $conn->close();
   if($result->num_rows > 0)
      {
           $r = $result->fetch_assoc();
          if($r['password'] === $password)
          {
     $this->setSession($r['user_id'],$r);
     return true;
          }else return false;
     }
     else
        return false;
        return false;

}


//Private DataBase Verification of User Credentials
private function verifySessionUser($user_id){
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$conn) die("Connection Error To DATABASE" . mysqli_errno());
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ?";
  $mysqli = $conn->prepare($sql);
  if(!$conn) die("Query Error To DATABASE In Class Session" . mysqli_errno());
  $mysqli->bind_param("d",$user_id);
  $mysqli->execute();
  $result = $mysqli->get_result();
  $mysqli->close();
  $conn->close();
   if($result->num_rows > 0)
      {
     return true;
     }
     else
        return false;
  }
}
```

**securepage.php**

```
$user = new Session();
   if($user->getSession() == true)
      {
         header("location: admin.php");
         exit();
       }
```

**Is there any security measures i should consider in future ?**

Comment: theoretically you could have multiple users that get the same key as it is based on useragent and ip

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ This might be a better place to ask for this kind of question.

Comment: Why not send the password with the initial query? Have SQL verify the password matches the account.

Comment: I wouldn't do `die("Query Error To DATABASE In Class Session" . mysqli_errno($conn))` in production. I'd send the user to an error page and log the error.

Comment: thank you all for comments , i would not use die command in production scripts ,

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you for your suggestions, what should i do to differentiate users behind NAT ? with same IP ?

Comment: not 100% foolproof but perhaps `function getRealIpAddr(){
  if( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
   $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
   $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }  else {
   $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  return $ip;
 }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Code  Review instead.